# can't delete directories from RAID trash

Tags: macos, raid, rm, trash

I have a 9TB RAID 0 comprised of 3x3TB drives. I can't delete some directories that have been moved to the trash.

```
Volumes/LTO
≈:≈ sudo rm -vrf ./.Trashes/
rm: ./.Trashes//503/c/c: Directory not empty
rm: ./.Trashes//503/c: Directory not empty
rm: ./.Trashes//503: Directory not empty
rm: ./.Trashes/: Directory not empty
/Volumes/LTO
≈:≈
```

I've changed permissions and tried pretty much everything I know how to remove these without erasing the RAID, which would suck.

Also, the directories, in fact, appear empty by any investigation I can do of them.

```
/Volumes/LTO/.Trashes
≈:≈ du -h
  0B    ./503/c/c
  0B    ./503/c
  0B    ./503
  0B    .

/Volumes/LTO
≈:≈ sudo rm -vfRPd /Volumes/LTO/.Trashes/
rm: /Volumes/LTO/.Trashes//503/c/c: Directory not empty
rm: /Volumes/LTO/.Trashes//503/c: Directory not empty
rm: /Volumes/LTO/.Trashes//503: Directory not empty
rm: /Volumes/LTO/.Trashes/: Directory not empty
/Volumes/LTO
≈:≈
```

If I try to empty trash via Finder it says "The operation can’t be completed because the item “c” is in use." But, nothing is using the items. I've restarted the computer several times.

```
/Volumes/LTO
≈:≈ lsof | grep /Volumes/LTO/.Trashes/503/c/

/Volumes/LTO
≈:≈
```

:(

Comment: Do you see any hidden files if you were to do ls -la In any of those directories?  What about ownership?  Does root own the folder structure for the directory and subdirectories of that path?

Comment: I know the raid array I have has a trash feature that clears out deleted files after a certain amount of time.  Have you checked to see if there might be a setting in whatever interface you are using to manage your array?

Comment: @Richie086 There are no hidden files. I `sudo chown -vR` ./.Trashes and I don't use any interface for my RAID, just the Terminal.

Comment: What about going to the /.Trashes//503/c directory and attempt to rm -vrf the /c: folder?  Does that produce the same result of the dir not being empty?

Comment: yes it does @Richie086

Comment: what about if you run du -h ./.Trashes/

Comment: Does it show any disk usage?

Comment: Alsowhat about rmdir -p --ignore-fail-on-non-empty ./.Trashes/  ?   that should do it I would think..   Your rmdir command might have different switches depending on what flavor of Linux you are using, but rmdir usually has a way to recursively delete a directory structure even if it is not empty,

Comment: @Richie086 see above edits. Thanks!

Comment: what was the result of  `sudo rmdir -p --ignore-on-non-empty ./Trashes/` ?   When you say 'finder', i assume you mean you are using a Mac.   Is that correct?

Comment: can you rename (move) any of the folders underneath `./.Trashes`?   `sudo mv /Volumes/LTO/.Trashes/503/c /Volumes/LTO/.Trashes/503/somethingelse'`

Comment: Yes, I'm on a Mac. `--remove-on-non-empty` is not an option I have but I can't see how it would be any different that `sudo rm -vfrPd` Yes, I can `mv` the folders/files and call them anything, but they still won't delete. The results are the same regardless of the name. @Richie086

Comment: Try 'rmdir --help'

Comment: I just deleted and remade the RAID. It was hopeless :p Thanks for the tips!